# RStan: Specifying a Three-Level Random Slopes Model?

Tags: r, bayesian, multi-level, rstan

I've been working on a three-level RStan model where repeated broadband measurements (year ID = yrid) are nested within local authorities (LA ID = laid), which are finally nested within regions (region ID = rnid). The (logged)dependent variable is speed and the (logged) predictors are population density (pd) and superfast broadband penetration (sfbb). Currently there are random intercepts at the local authority and regional level (levels 2 & 3).

How do I extend the model to have a random slope at either level 1 or level 2?

Here's a subset of data, the RStan model and the overall R code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 library(rstan)
 ###Data
  yrid = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
     21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
     41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,
     61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,
     81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,
     101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,
     121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,
     141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,
     161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,
     181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199)
  laid <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,
     6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,
     11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,
     16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,
     21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,
     26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,
     31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,
     36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,
     41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,
     46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,50,50,50)
 rnid <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
     2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
     3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,
     4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
     4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
     5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
     6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
     7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8)
pd <- c(7.59262,7.59875,7.6027,7.60375,7.5301,7.53444,7.53604,7.54136,8.378,8.3936,
   8.40061,8.41183,7.36682,7.36992,7.37607,7.38268,7.20065,7.2011,7.20162,7.20578,
   7.78846,7.79947,7.80743,7.81992,7.71797,7.72011,7.72396,7.73026,7.66336,7.66561,
   7.66744,7.66833,7.66973,7.67587,7.68327,7.69321,7.4326,7.43449,7.43762,7.44167,
   7.43053,7.43053,7.43189,7.43396,8.33459,8.34315,8.34548,8.35036,7.15921,7.16325,
   7.16379,7.16943,7.4898,7.48869,7.48689,7.48796,7.61918,7.62046,7.62075,7.62261,
   6.55763,6.56541,6.57438,6.58286,6.27777,6.27833,6.28133,6.28339,6.80184,6.8045,
   6.80572,6.81113,7.31315,7.32324,7.32804,7.33446,7.24893,7.24843,7.24744,7.24993,
   7.80751,7.81927,7.83475,7.84514,7.80045,7.80147,7.80543,7.80792,7.74119,7.74253,
   7.74323,7.74457,7.6027,7.6042,7.60564,7.60852,8.29695,8.30721,8.31356,8.32186,
   8.07527,8.09465,8.11516,8.13795,8.06994,8.07091,8.07347,8.07788,8.19141,8.19883,
   8.20841,8.21603,7.05652,7.05893,7.06613,7.07089,7.85991,7.86511,7.8699,7.87721,
   8.18894,8.19332,8.19572,8.20125,7.26382,7.26669,7.2701,7.27351,6.32972,6.33505,
   6.34036,6.34529,6.94235,6.94832,6.95483,6.96111,7.21575,7.22504,7.23006,7.23648,
   6.87109,6.87472,6.8811,6.88623,6.89163,6.89264,6.89811,6.897,7.85077,7.85294,
   7.85438,7.85582,6.31409,6.31264,6.31192,6.31264,6.84119,6.84428,6.84843,6.85309,
   6.28171,6.27796,6.27983,6.27983,5.43764,5.44025,5.44328,5.44674,4.14155,4.14155,
   4.13996,4.14155,5.76142,5.76519,5.76676,5.77082,7.37092,7.37092,7.37331,7.37651,
   7.02322,7.02811,7.035,7.04132,5.88444,5.88666,5.88915,5.89275,6.98296,6.98296,
   6.98091,6.97616,8.31179,8.3111,8.30687,8.30048,8.18502,8.1893,8.19085)
 sfbb <- c(4.41884,4.47506,4.53903,4.52179,4.49981,4.51196,4.55071,4.48864,4.35671,4.39938,
     4.46245,4.46591,4.47734,4.54966,4.57883,4.54329,4.06044,4.40305,4.56643,4.5326,
     4.31749,4.44265,4.51196,4.48864,4.54329,4.56643,4.59107,4.55388,4.45435,4.52287,
     4.5401,4.49981,4.46591,4.51525,4.53903,4.49981,4.46591,4.4613,4.54116,4.51086,
     4.33073,4.33598,4.45435,4.45435,4.34381,4.41159,4.45435,4.45435,4.41884,4.42365,
     4.46476,4.40672,4.21951,4.32281,4.50756,4.51086,4.09434,4.12552,4.26127,4.34381,
     4.27667,4.18662,4.25277,4.26268,4.00733,4.10264,4.33205,4.34381,4.00733,4.01638,
     4.28497,4.33073,4.2485,4.27528,4.39815,4.33073,4.21951,4.23989,4.2683,4.31749,
     4.14313,4.25277,4.31615,4.41884,4.07754,4.21951,4.37701,4.40672,4.34381,4.34381,
     4.50976,4.48864,4.00733,4.27528,4.51305,4.51086,4.45435,4.4762,4.51961,4.5326,
     4.18965,4.21951,4.46476,4.49981,4.52179,4.51525,4.56017,4.54329,4.35671,4.34899,
     4.38701,4.44265,4.48864,4.48639,4.51086,4.51086,4.46591,4.49088,4.51852,4.49981,
     4.5326,4.53475,4.57471,4.56435,4.39445,4.45783,4.52721,4.46591,4.02535,4.0656,
     4.20469,4.11087,4.04305,4.27805,4.37952,4.38203,4.40672,4.38203,4.4613,4.44265,
     3.98898,4.29046,4.43912,4.40672,4.47734,4.52829,4.53582,4.51086,4.51086,4.5326,
     4.55808,4.52179,4.46591,4.47734,4.50866,4.46591,4.43082,4.48639,4.51196,4.47734,
     4.41884,4.41643,4.46014,4.47734,3.09104,4.0448,4.13517,4.17439,2.19722,3.59731,
     3.90399,4.15888,4.20469,4.38701,4.4128,4.34381,4.18965,4.19117,4.42843,4.44265,
     4.33073,4.34251,4.37827,4.44265,3.7612,4.08092,4.1987,4.2485,4.12713,4.12228,
     4.22098,4.30407,4.14313,4.13677,4.29456,4.45435,-2.30259,1.52606,2.49321)
   speed <- c(2.10413,2.76632,2.95491,3.29953,1.96009,2.57261,2.81541,3.11795,2.10413,2.56495,
      2.8792,3.17805,1.94591,2.7213,2.96011,3.30689,1.93152,2.38876,2.82731,3.19867,
      2.20827,2.82731,3.03495,3.35341,2.17475,2.82138,3.10459,3.44362,2.04122,2.5416,
      2.83321,3.15274,2.14007,2.68102,3.06805,3.36384,2.15176,2.63189,3.03495,3.36384,
      2.05412,2.49321,2.91235,3.28091,2.25129,2.67415,2.96011,3.32504,2.07944,2.55723,
      2.98568,3.31054,2.17475,2.61007,2.83321,3.2884,2.11626,2.5416,2.79728,3.15274,
      1.93152,2.5337,2.70805,3.02529,1.97408,2.52573,2.7213,3.06805,1.97408,2.4248,
      2.63189,2.97553,1.97408,2.52573,2.73437,3.03975,2.17475,2.57261,2.96527,3.22684,
      2.17475,2.68785,2.93386,3.22684,2.09186,2.71469,2.91777,3.24649,2.10413,2.58022,
      3.03495,3.39786,1.93152,2.38876,2.89037,3.21888,2.18605,2.70805,3.03013,3.36038,
      2.11626,2.50144,2.89591,3.2308,2.14007,2.59525,3.03013,3.36384,2.16332,2.61007,
      2.9069,3.20275,2.11626,2.83321,3.09104,3.40784,2.10413,2.59525,2.96011,3.26957,
      2.20827,2.95491,3.10009,3.46574,2.11626,2.58776,2.94969,3.24649,1.91692,2.50144,
      2.63906,2.97041,1.94591,2.451,2.78501,3.11795,2.06686,2.5416,2.9069,3.2308,
      1.91692,2.41591,2.66026,2.98568,2.06686,2.93386,3.14415,3.47816,2.19722,2.91777,
      3.15274,3.44362,2.15176,2.8679,3.10459,3.421,2.11626,2.74084,3.13983,3.45947,
      2.05412,2.57261,3.03013,3.38439,1.84055,2.24071,2.4681,2.74727,1.84055,2.11626,
      2.35138,2.66723,1.90211,2.50144,2.76001,3.054,2.00148,2.41591,2.8679,3.24259,
      2.0149,2.5096,2.91235,3.26194,1.90211,2.37024,2.6174,2.92316,1.98787,2.52573,
      2.69463,3.05871,2.25129,2.80336,2.90142,3.2581,1.98787,2.2192,2.34181)


 total <- data.frame(speed, pd, sfbb, yrid, laid, rnid)

 ## Create a vector of school IDs where j-th element gives school ID for class ID j
 regionLookupVec <- unique(total[c("laid","rnid")])[,"rnid"]

 ## Design matrix for model 
 desMat <- model.matrix(object = ~ 1 + pd + sfbb , data = total)

 ## Combine as a stan dataset
 Ni <- length(unique(total$yrid))
 Nj <- length(unique(total$laid))
 Nk <- length(unique(total$rnid))              
 p  <- ncol(desMat)
 desMat <-(desMat)
 laid <- (total$laid)
 rnid <- (total$rnid)
 regionLookup <- (regionLookupVec)
 speed <- (total$speed)

 ## Combine as a stan dataset
 dat <- (list(    Ni           = Ni,
                  Nj           = Nj,
                  Nk           = Nk,
                  p            = p,
                  desMat       = desMat,
                  laid         = laid,
                  rnid         = rnid,
                  regionLookup = regionLookupVec,
                  speed        = speed))
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   #load model
   stanmodelcode <- "data {
 ##Define variables in data
 ##Number of level-1 observations (an integer)
 int<lower=0> Ni;
 ## Number of level-2 clusters
 int<lower=0> Nj;
 ## Number of level-3 clusters
 int<lower=0> Nk;
 ##Number of fixed effect parameters
 int<lower=0> p;
 // Design matrix
 real desMat[Ni,p];
 ## Cluster IDs
 int<lower=1> laid[Ni];
 int<lower=1> rnid[Ni];
 ## Level 3 look up vector for level 2
 int<lower=1> regionLookup[Nj];
 ## Continuous outcome
 real speed[Ni];
 ## Continuous predictor
 ## real X_1ijk[Ni];
 }
 parameters {
 ## Define parameters to estimate
 ## Fixed effects (a real number)
 real beta[p];
 ## Level-1 errors
 real<lower=0> sigma_e0;
 ## Level-2 random effect
 real u_0jk[Nj];
 real<lower=0> sigma_u0jk;
 ## Level-3 random effect
 real u_0k[Nk];
 real<lower=0> sigma_u0k;
 }

 transformed parameters  {
 ## Varying intercepts
 real beta_0jk[Nj];
 real beta_0k[Nk];
 ## Individual mean
 real mu[Ni];
 ## Varying intercepts definition
 ## Level-3 (level-3 random intercepts)
 for (k in 1:Nk) {
 beta_0k[k] <- beta[1] + u_0k[k];
 }
 ## Level-2 (level-2 random intercepts)
 for (j in 1:Nj) {
 beta_0jk[j] <- beta_0k[regionLookup[j]] + u_0jk[j];
 }
 ## Individual mean
 for (i in 1:Ni) {
 mu[i] <- beta_0jk[laid[i]] +
 desMat[i,2]*beta[2] + 
 desMat[i,3]*beta[3];
 }
 }
 model {
 ## Prior part of Bayesian inference
 ## Flat prior for mu (no need to specify if non-informative)
 ## Random effects distribution
 u_0k  ~ normal(0, sigma_u0k);
 u_0jk ~ normal(0, sigma_u0jk);
 ## Likelihood part of Bayesian inference
 ## Outcome model N(mu, sigma^2) (use SD rather than Var)
 for (i in 1:Ni) {
 speed[i] ~ normal(mu[i], sigma_e0);
 }
 }"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 resStan <-stan(model_code = stanmodelcode, data=dat, iter=100, chains=2, warmup=10, 
                  thin=1, control=list(adapt_delta = 0.9), verbose = TRUE)
```

Pulling out the stan code for readability:

```
data {
     ##Define variables in data
     ##Number of level-1 observations (an integer)
     int<lower=0> Ni;
     ## Number of level-2 clusters
     int<lower=0> Nj;
     ## Number of level-3 clusters
     int<lower=0> Nk;
     ##Number of fixed effect parameters
     int<lower=0> p;
     // Design matrix
     real desMat[Ni,p];
     ## Cluster IDs
     int<lower=1> laid[Ni];
     int<lower=1> rnid[Ni];
     ## Level 3 look up vector for level 2
     int<lower=1> regionLookup[Nj];
     ## Continuous outcome
     real speed[Ni];
     ## Continuous predictor
     ## real X_1ijk[Ni];
   }
   parameters {
     ## Define parameters to estimate
     ## Fixed effects (a real number)
     real beta[p];
     ## Level-1 errors
     real<lower=0> sigma_e0;
     ## Level-2 random effect
     real u_0jk[Nj];
     real<lower=0> sigma_u0jk;
     ## Level-3 random effect
     real u_0k[Nk];
     real<lower=0> sigma_u0k;
   }

   transformed parameters  {
     ## Varying intercepts
     real beta_0jk[Nj];
     real beta_0k[Nk];
     ## Individual mean
     real mu[Ni];
     ## Varying intercepts definition
     ## Level-3 (level-3 random intercepts)
     for (k in 1:Nk) {
       beta_0k[k] <- beta[1] + u_0k[k];
     }
     ## Level-2 (level-2 random intercepts)
     for (j in 1:Nj) {
       beta_0jk[j] <- beta_0k[regionLookup[j]] + u_0jk[j];
     }
     ## Individual mean
     for (i in 1:Ni) {
       mu[i] <- beta_0jk[laid[i]] +
       desMat[i,2]*beta[2] + 
       desMat[i,3]*beta[3];
     }
   }
   model {
     ## Prior part of Bayesian inference
     ## Flat prior for mu (no need to specify if non-informative)
     ## Random effects distribution
     u_0k  ~ normal(0, sigma_u0k);
     u_0jk ~ normal(0, sigma_u0jk);
     ## Likelihood part of Bayesian inference
     ## Outcome model N(mu, sigma^2) (use SD rather than Var)
     for (i in 1:Ni) {
       speed[i] ~ normal(mu[i], sigma_e0);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want random effects at both levels, you just need to do the same thing again.  So let's say you have an item y[n], who belongs to first level group gg[n] in 1:G, and that group g belongs to second level group hh[g] in 1:H.  Then you just have the random intercept parameters

```
vector[G] c;
vector[H] d;
```

and then the regression just does the index fiddling

```
for (n in 1:N)
  mu[n] <- ... + c[gg[n]] + d[hh[gg[n]];
```

I'd also strongly recommend not including the Stan program as a string --- it messes up the ability to use print statements (or transpositions) and you lose the line numbers.  And indenting to make the blocks more easily scannable.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I'll check this out. And I'll also move the Stan program into a different file for calling separately.